# C Headers (GCC)

Tags: header, include

I am trying to compile some scripts from exploit-db by using GCC (Linux Debian), and when I issue the gcc command to compile the code (`gcc -o test test.c`) I'm getting a message that says that the files "linux/linkage.h" and "asm/page.h" could not be found.

When I issued a command $ locate linkage.h, I found that these files are in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-common/include/linux/linkage.h` and `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-common/include/asm/page.h` respectively.

Is there any way to tell GCC to consider this path or maybe change the standard path?

Below you can find a few lines of the code that I am trying to compile.

```
/*
 * Linux kernel 2.4 uselib() privilege elevation exploit.
 *
 * original exploit source from http://isec.pl
 * reference: http://isec.pl/vulnerabilities/isec-0021-uselib.txt
 *
 * I modified the Paul Starzetz's exploit, made it more possible
 * to race successfully. The exploit still works only on 2.4 series.  
 * It should be also works on 2.4 SMP, but not easy. 
 *
 * thx newbug.
 *
 * Tim Hsu <timhsu at chroot.org> Jan 2005.
 *
 */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

#include <linux/elf.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>

#include <asm/page.h>
#include <asm/ldt.h>
#include <asm/segment.h>

#define str(s) #s
#define xstr(s) str(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the include flag,

```
gcc -I"/usr/src/linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-common/include/" -o test test.c
```